# How can a copula be seen as a characterization of association?

Tags: probability, independence, cumulative-distribution-function, copula

On the post [*A formal definition of a “measure of association”*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association) [@kjetil b halvorsen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen) commented the following:

> A copula could be seen as a characterization of association, so maybe a "measure of association" is a functional of the bivariate distribution (,) that only depends on the copula (,).

From Wikipedia:

> [A map] $C: [0,1]^d \mapsto [0,1]$ is a $d$-dimensional **copula** if $C$ is a joint distribution of ad $d$-dimensional random vector on the unit cube $[0,1]^d$ with uniform marginals.

With Sklar's theorem I can see how this is a useful mathematical tool for studying distributions in general, but it hasn't hit me yet why the [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) is a characterization of association. At this moment it seems more like a [multivariate CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Multivariate_case) with normalized [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)), and it isn't clear to me that a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) of a CDF which depends on the copula would necessarily be a measure of association.

Just as [mutual independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) for a collection of random variables $\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$ can be given by the satisfying of the equality $F_{X_1, \cdots, X_n}(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \prod_{j}^{n} F_{x_j}(x_j)$, do we simply rephrase this in terms of the copulas?

$$C_{X_1, \cdots, X_n}(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \prod_{j}^{n} C_{x_j}(x_j)$$

How can a copula be seen as a characterization of association?

> Footnote: There are some related questions that are interesting but do not address my question.
>
> - [Questions concerning copulas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62961/questions-concerning-copulas)
> - [Trying to wrap my arms around copulas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363476/trying-to-wrap-my-arms-around-copulas)
> - [showing that a function is a copula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179612/showing-that-a-function-is-a-copula)

Comment: I posted two questions last year that are possibly of interest: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/510992/copula-entropy-calculation-is-borked) [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511088/mutual-information-relationship-to-copula-entropy-is-borked).

Comment: Oops, I posted those earlier this year. Anyway, the key point is that, if we can rectify what I question in those two posts (what I call "borked" about the relationship between mutual information, copula, and copula entropy calculation), then the copula has an intimate relationship with the mutual information.

Comment: I hate to say it, but isn't this a trivial observation?  The copula factors out the univariate marginal distributions, which *obviously* have nothing to do with any concept of "association."  Thus, any measure of association perforce is some functional of the copula.

Comment: @whuber It may seem [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviality_(mathematics)) [*prima facie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prima_facie), but I've asked in case I missed something counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @whuber: It is not that trivial, the Pearson correlation is not a functional of the copula ...

Comment: @Kjetil That's an interesting observation.  Maybe it says something important about Pearson correlation!

Comment: If Pearson's R is a measure of association, and Pearson's R is not a functional of the copula, then not all measures of association are a functional of a copula.

Comment: Copula can measure the dependency through its dependency parameters.